# How do you write a literal backtick in the beginning of a markdown code block?

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I know that to represent a literal backtick inside a code block, I could start with a "different number of backticks"

```
``foo ` bar``
```

This produces:

`` foo ` bar ``

However, what if I want my literal backtick to be the *beginning* of the code block? i.e:

````
```foo bar``
````

This does not work:

```foo bar``

If I add a space in the beginning, it will:

`` `foo bar ``

Is there a way I can achieve this without a space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a space at the beginning *and the end:*

```
`` `foo bar ``
```

This renders as

`` `foo bar ``

both on Stack Overflow and GitHub.